# I am confused in modeling rayleigh fading channel

Tags: channel

I am new to wireless communication and want to model a wireless communication system

```
y = h * s + n
```

where `h = x + iy` and `|h|` follow rayleigh distribution

However, I am confused about the following code
what should I use

```
h = np.abs((np.random.randn(n)+1j*np.random.randn(n))*(1/np.sqrt(2)))
```

or

```
h = (np.random.randn(n)+1j*np.random.randn(n))*(1/np.sqrt(2))
```

Comment: You should make sure that you understand the theory before attempting any code. I'd suggest figuring out what is the distribution of `real(h)` and `imag(h)` first.